# On iOS, how to fill a path with an outline? (or both fill and stroke the path)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics

On iOS, if we do

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(contextFoo, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextFoo, x, y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextFoo, x2, y2);
// ... and many more CGContextAddLineToPoint
```

then after this, if we do a `CGContextStrokePath`, we will get an outline, or if we `CGContextFillPath`, we get the "fill", but we can't do both, because after a stroke or a fill, the "current path" is gone.  How can we both fill and stroke a path (such as wanting a yellow fill and orange outline)?

We can move the `MoveTo` and `AddLine` calls to a function, and call that function, do a fill, and call the function again, and do a stroke, but there are many `x` and `y` that makes passing all of them to the function quite troublesome.  What might be some ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
// to both Fill and Stroke your context
// or kCGPathFill/kCGPathStroke to only fill/stroke
```

you can save your Path btw (to reuse it for multiple things of same shape) using:

CGPathBeginPath/MoveToPoint/AddLine/... very similar to CGContext/...

For your example:

```
[[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];                      
[[UIColor orangeColor] setStroke];

CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```